# How can I remove expressionengine default member templates?

Tags: expressionengine

I've just realised I have a site that has the default member profile forms online at /member/register

I don't use these and instead have templates using Zoo Visitor and can't for the life of me find where I can disable the default ones. I need to disable these as they are being found by bots.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I disable via htaccess:

```
# Prevent direct access to EE Member area
# ------------------------------
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (member)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}/404 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. Shame there's no setting to have it disabled in EE but it works.

Comment: Old answer, but just what I was looking  for, great way of doing this! Many thanks...

Answer (score 3):

I do it by making the profile trigger totally random.

In your config file add:

```
$config['profile_trigger'] = rand(0,time());
```

Answer (score 3):

We've also done this which seems to work:

In the CP go to Members > Preferences and in the general configuration block there is a field for 'Profile Triggering Word'. Adding a '#' to this prevents the default templates showing.